# Retrieve posts by category name issue in WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've created a custom page template for my "Topics" Page.

What I want to do is add in some PHP to the custom page template my Topics page uses, to retrieve permalinks for the 3 most recent posts from a chosen category.

```
E.g.
(From post category 1)

--> Permalink for post 1

--> Permalink for post 2

--> Permalink for post 3
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
           <ul>
    <?php
    $category_posts = new WP_Query('cat=consumer-trust&showposts=3');
    while ($category_posts ->have_posts()) : $category_posts->the_post();?>
    <li>
    <a class="yourclass" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem, however, is that changing the cat in the WP_Query doesn't seem to make any difference. I've tried numbers and category names, and neither works.

Can anybody advise? This code will appear three times on the intended page, for three different categories.

Comment: When you tried category name, did you change the parameter to `category_name`, not `cat` (and use the slug, not the name)?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'cat_name','meta_key'=>'_pr_date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value','order'=>'DESC') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I've managed to find an answer:

```
<?php global $post; // required
$args = array('category' => 18); // include category 18
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

// put here what you want to appear for each post like:
//the title:
the_title();   

endforeach;

?>
```